# Hallo.js - Rangy is not defined

Tags: javascript, rangy, hallo-js

I just tried to add the Hallo.js editor to my website. It kind of works, but as soon as I'm editing a text, I see the following error in Chrome and Firefox. In Opera it seems to work fine.

```
rangy is not defined (sel = rangy.getSelection();    Line 2674 in hallo.js)
```

You can find an example of that behaviour on JSBin: http://jsbin.com/unuces/2/

In the [documentation of hallo.js](https://github.com/bergie/hallo) there's no dependency for rangy mentioned, so I think it should not be needed. Does anyone already have experience on that one?

Thank you for your help.

====  **Solution:** ========

**Rangy is not defined**

This occurs when rangy is not included. For Hallojs to work rangy has to be included.

**...has no method getSelected**

This happens if rangy is loaded dynamically. To solve this error call rangy.init() after loading it.

Comment: it seems its dependent on Rangy, see:: https://github.com/bergie/hallo/issues/123

Comment: Thank you, thought because they said "isn't dependent since 1.0" it really isn't dependend anymore

Comment: so please, don't leave it unanswered. Don't add your answer in the question, but answer the question yourself below! \/

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/bergie/hallo/issues/159)